# Validate Form on Change ONLY

Tags: smartclient

Because much of our imported data technically has validation errors, users are unable to update fields without first correcting previously entered bad data. This wouldn't be a problem except that many times this user doesn't have the information needed to enter a correct value into that field but we still need to save their update.

Is it possible to disable the validate on submit for a `DynamicForm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could find thus far.

I'm disabling validation and overridding `getValues`, which is called as part of `saveData` so I manually parse through any fields and look for errors. If I find an error I remove it from the return value and store it under the `valuesManager.invalidatedFields`.

If a field had an error it will not be included in the save, but because the server will return the original value I had to override `setValues` as well to prevent your (bad) change from being overridden.

Also, because `getValues` is called on initial load it validates on load as well.

```
isc.ValuesManager.create({
    disableValidation: true,
    invalidatedFields: {},
    setValues: function(values){
        console.log("setting values..", this.invalidatedFields);
        for (var key in this.invalidatedFields) {
            if (this.invalidatedFields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                values[key] = this.invalidatedFields[key];
            }
        }
        this.Super("setValues", arguments);
    },
    getValues: function () {
        this.invalidatedFields = [];
        var data = this.Super("getValues");
        for (var key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var form = this.getMemberForField(key);
                if (form && !form.getField(key).validate()) {
                    console.log(key + " failed validation", data[key]);
                    this.invalidatedFields[key] = data[key];
                    delete data[key];
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to disable the validate on submit for a DynamicForm?

there's a disableValidation attribute, it disables client-side validators.

Comment: thank you for the quick response, while this does prevent the validate on submit that I'm looking for, it also breaks validate on change which I'd like to preserve.. any ideas?